# Google Chrome расширения

Tags: google-chrome

Есть такие файлы

`manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "domchel",
  "description": "domchel",
  "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "browser-action.png",
        "default_title": "http://domchel.ru/"

    } ,
   "content_scripts" : [
    {
      "matches" : [
        "http://domchel.ru/*",
        "http://dom.63.ru/*"
      ],
      "js" : ["contentscript.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

`contentscript.js`:

```
function init(c){}
```

`background.js`:

```
var counter = 0;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
       counter++;
    
    if (counter%2 == 0)
    {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"browser-action.png"})
    
        //сhrome.tabs.executeScript(id,{code:"init("+counter+")"})
    } else {
        chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"browser-action_no.png"})
    }
});
```

Как правильно передать из `background.js` в `contentscript.js` переменную `counter`?

так не идет

```
 сhrome.tabs.executeScript(id,{code:"init("+counter+")"})
```

что-то не то делаю... кто хорошо знает эту тему, подскажите.

Comment: @alekslv, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: спасибо..дошло  а то тут первый раз спрашиваю..не мог вубаться